# Laravel admin section for CRUD

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to create an admin section (**for myself**) in the website where **not a lot** of functionality is required.

Basically, I need to do mostly CRUD operations on articles I publish on the website and possibly have a another view of registered users table. Nothing crazy.

I read some articles about multiple authentication in Laravel, but I'm not sure if it fits my use case. I need a simple solution that will be robust.

I thought about adding a simple isAdmin column to the users table and to manually add myself to that table through phpmyadmin, so only I will have access to the admin views (by checking Auth::user->isAdmin === true)

Not so experienced in this so your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest using Laravel's built-in ACL (roles and permissions) before having multiple `User` types. It's not to say having different user types doesn't have it's place, I've just found the permissions route to be more flexible in the long run. This approach would also tie-in nicely with your `isAdmin()` method. https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization

Comment: By using `laravel AUTH` and create table for every type of user , your website has more security. it's not hard or complex.

Comment: As others had mentioned, you can use the Laravel Auth system, alongside with Authorization system, you can use middleware too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication) using:

```
PHP artisan make:auth
```

then use the middleware. It is the easiest way for beginners but if you have the experience, you can use sessions and your own authentication.